# British English grammar rules governing stative verbs

Tags: british-english

I seem to have run into a Russian teacher of English who thinks she is the be-all and end-all when it comes to British English grammar.  She is absolutely insisting that the sentence below is wrong, wrong, wrong, according to British grammatical rules governing stative verbs.

> It is closer I think to what Giancarlo was wanting to say.

I say there is nothing wrong with the sentence.

Your verdict, please.

Comment: Is "I think" meant to be parenthetical in there, i.e. "I think it is closer to what Ciancarlo was wanting to say"? It's helpful to offset such phrases in commas.

Comment: @Stuart F I like 'helpful' rather than 'obligatory' there!

Comment: Hello, T. Perhaps it might be better to remove the personal references and stick to 'A teacher of English has advised me that the sentence below is ...'.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you can tell her to complain to the [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/want) grammarians. Their *verdict* says:

> Most uses of ***want*** involve the *simple forms* of the verb (*want, wants, wanted*). ***When we are talking about wishes or desires we can also use the continuous form*** (*is wanting, **was wanting**, will be wanting*).

Plus!

> We can use ***want*** in the *continuous form* **to show indirectness or politeness**:
>
> - Customer:
>   *We’re wanting* to buy a new TV, but we’re not sure what to get.
>   Assistant:
>   Okay, sir. Let me show you some of them.

And finally:

> We can also use the continuous form ***to emphasise an ongoing or repeated process***:
>
> - We’d been wanting to go to New Zealand for years, so his sixtieth birthday was a good excuse.

Comment: My sincerest thanks!  I haven't quite figured out what constitutes an acceptable on-topic question, but I shall endeavor to do so.  I signed up because time and again, I have found Stack Exchange has provided the final word on many of my grammatical queries.

Comment: Yes, this site might come across as unwelcoming at first, but that's because it does have strict and high standards. A look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) might help. And welcome :)

Comment: I can only hear *was wanting* as lacking: The Lord is my shepherd, I shall not want. Measured and weighed, you've been found wanting.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Yes, I've been found wanting to decipher your riddle as usual! :) I got the Daniel 5:27 part. I _think_ :D

Comment: Yes, as usual, we don't see our own riddles as other than speaking. "I shall not want" means "With God's guidance, I will not be *lacking* (Hebrew: missing anything), not desiring.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine. I would add commas to make it easier to read, but this is just personal preference.

> It is closer, I think, to what Giancarlo was wanting to say.

Compared to "... what Giancarlo wanted to say", the original sentence puts subtle emphasis on Giancarlo's eagarness to say it.